# Ffmpeg overlay using filter complex taking too much cpu

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I am relaying a input rtmp stream to different server. In one of the use case, i overlay a image on top of the stream using filter complex and scale2ref, but it is taking almost 10 times the cpu as compared to normal ffmpeg command.

overlay: 'ffmpeg -xerror -itsoffset ${delaySeconds} -i ${SOURCERTMP} -i ${overlayUrl} -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[ovr][base];[base][ovr] overlay=0:0, split=1[a]" -map 0:a -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize '${forwardUrls[0]}'

simple Version: 'ffmpeg -xerror -itsoffset ${delaySeconds} -i ${SOURCERTMP} -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize '${forwardUrls[0]}'

Answer (score 0):

It's not taking too much CPU, Its taking the CPU it needs. That is expected. The second command is doing MUCH less than the first.

The overlay command is not just adding an overlay. It is decoding the video, blitting an overlay, then reencoding the video (which is very expensive), And possibly doing some automatic color space conversation.

The "simple version" is just reading an encoded frame, and writing it back out without looking at it. Its basically a file copy.

Frankly I'm supposed its only 10x more CPU.

Comment: Yes, it is taking more than 10xCpu in practical. But is there any other optimised way through which I can achieve the first use case

Comment: It’s already “optimized”. That’s just how long it takes.